# Rails on Heroku: git add environment.rb or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I usually git-ignore config/environment.rb file. I add ENV['RAILS_ENV'] setting into that file so it should be different on different machine.

However, Heroku requires that file in git. Without it, the application crashes.

How do you handle it?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: That's a critical file in a Rails app. You certainly need to add it to git if you plan to push your code to Heroku. What do you mean when you say you add `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` to the file?

Comment: I know it's a critical file. I just have different environment.rb on each machine so that I can have different env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't ignore `config/environment.rb`. As Zeke already answered, you can set environment variables in a live Heroku app.

To see a list of environment variables available to your heroku app run `heroku config`. To set the value of an specific variable run `heroku config:add RAILS_ENV=staging --app yourapp`.

But what about your development app running in your own machine? There are some options, one is exporting an environment variable in your shell:

```
$ export RAILS_ENV=staging
$ echo $RAILS_ENV
staging
```

But I prefer another approach. This is what I have in my `config/environment.rb`:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Load environment vars from local file
env_vars = File.join(Rails.root.to_s, 'config', 'env_vars.rb')
load(env_vars) if File.exists?(env_vars)

# Initialize the rails application
MyApp::Application.initialize!
```

If there is a `config/env_vars.rb` file, it will be loaded. This is the contents of a sample `env_vars.rb` file:

```
ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]  = 'redis://localhost:6379'
ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"] = '283983483'
ENV["AWS_SECRET"]     = '743843934'
ENV["S3_BUCKET"]      = 'myapp-development'
```

This way you could have different sets of environment variables for your development, staging and production apps.

**You will want to git-ignore this file**.

While I'm running my development app I want to send files to a `myapp-development` S3 bucket. But I want my production app (in Heroku) to send files to a `myapp-production` S3 bucket.

```
$ heroku config:add S3_BUCKET='myapp-production'  --app myapp
```

And a different bucket for my staging app (also running in Heroku):

```
$ heroku config:add S3_BUCKET='myapp-staging'  --app myapp-staging
```

Since you'll git-ignore `config/env_vars.rb`, it will not be present in your apps running in Heroku, and so they'll get their environment variables from the above `heroku config:add` configurations.

---

Since I work with other people, I often include an example `env_vars.rb.example` file in the project, which is not ignored by git:

File `config/env_vars.rb.example`:

```
# Copy this file to config/env_vars.rb
# MAKE SURE THAT YOUR .gitignore INCLUDES IT!
#
# This file is used to set environment variables that would be present on
# Heroku, and are needed for our development and test instances to run.
ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]  = 'redis://localhost:6379'
ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"] = 'xxx'
ENV["AWS_SECRET"]     = 'xxx'
ENV["S3_BUCKET"]      = 'some-bucket'

if Rails.env.test?
  HOST = "example.com"
else
  HOST = "development.intranet"
end
```

Notice that an advantage of loading this `env_vars.rb` file is that you can do different things programmatically, for example setting the `HOST` constant to a different value if you are running your tests, like above.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has [pretty great documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/). To answer your question directly, they provide and interface to [configure environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#production-and-development-modes). They even [provide a mechanism](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#managing-staging-and-production-configurations) that makes deploying to two+ Heroku-hosted apps with different environments quite easy.